# R: what can be a specific use of stop() function in R debugging?

Tags: r

I read some examples of using `stop()` in R.

Usually, `stop()` was put somewhere in a function.

What is difference from using following code :

```
print('some error may be here') # as stop() also prints a message
return(NULL) # this can also stop the function immediately
```

So how we can better use of `stop()` in debug then? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`stop()` is used to prevent subsequent code from running. It's often used in more complex functions that have checks built in to avoid running complex computations if there is likely to be an error.

For example, say I have a function that takes a numeric vector as input, but if the user doesn't provide a numeric vector, I want to stop the function and return an error message.

```
some_fun <- function(x) {

  if(!is.numeric(x)) {
     stop("x is not numeric") # use stop to prevent rest of function from running
  }

  # Complex computations...
}

> some_fun(c("a", "b", "c"))
Error in some_fun(c("a", "b", "c")) : x is not numeric
```

Comment: It's worth noting that R has another builtin function `stopifnot` which is more succinct in these cases. We could replace the `if` block with `stopifnot("x is not numeric" = is.numeric(x))`